# Can I drive a car in Paris if I have an Indian driving licence?

Tags: indian-citizens, paris, driving-licenses

I am going to Paris for a vacation with a few friends next month. I have my driving license issued in India. Can I drive a car there with this ID? If not, will any other ID let me to legally drive a car there?

Comment: Are you considering driving inside the city? I'd advice against it. Although I've not been in Paris for ages it's likely very busy, parking will be expensive and the metro (subway) system is very likely a better option.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje Yes, I mean, driving someone else's car on the roads of Paris. There stays one of my relative, and was thinking to take his car for our whole vacation period, so that we can explore the city in our own way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You DO NOT need/want a car to explore Paris and nearby attractions.

Paris is (relatively) small and dense and has a good subway and bus network.

As a tourist, walking and using public transport is the way to go.

Everything is accessible by public transportation, even the major attractions outside Paris, Versailles, Euro Disneyland,...

Even If you want to do a day trip to to a nearby city (for example Reims, Strasbourg, Anger, ... ) Using the train will be cheaper and easier than driving.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an International Driving Permit? That's basically an official translation of your license, not a permit in its own right.

If so, you should be able to drive a car in France since France recognizes the IDP.

Comment: No @o.m. I don't have an IDP. It's just a National Driving License, valid in India only...

Comment: You can get an IDP in India; it's just a multilingual translation of your existing license, for someone who doesn't read Hindi and English (or whatever languages are on your license). However, let me echo the other commenter that traffic and parking are very difficult in Paris. The metro and suburban rail (RER) are a far better idea. Unlike the systems in some Indian cities, they cover the entire metropolis. You do not need a car anywhere.

Comment: What about insurance?